# Connecting app with SQL server on Ubuntu server

Tags: php, sql

Maybe I should ask this question in the Ubuntu section instead, but don't really know where the problem is so I'm trying here first.

I'm trying to learn how to use SQL database through a webserver, and I've used this tutorial: [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

I've done everything like in the tutorial, but I'm using Ubuntu server, not windows.

The problem is that the app is not able to display or create any entries from/in the database. I use PHPMyAdmin to manage the SQL database.

**1. So my main question: Is there any difference between WAMP/LAMP? Or can I use the same approach?**

If the answer is YES, then I have some more questions:

1. I'm using the default location for my server /var/www/ and have put all the .php files there? Correct?
2. When he makes the db_config.php he uses "localhost" but I want to use my ip instead, do I just have to change "localhost" to "81.xxx.xxx.xxx" or do I need to add something more?

As you can see I'm not really sure where the problem is, if it's the compability between the tutorial and the LAMP server instead of WAMP, or if it's the config of the connection, something in the php codes, the placement of the php files or whatever?

It's so frustrating because I don't know where to start.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
I can access the php files on the server so no problem there. 
This is from my access.log file when trying to list all items: `[09/Oct/2013:16:56:07 +0200] "GET /var/www/get_all_products.php? HTTP/1.1" 404 450 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"`
This is when I try to create a new product: `[09/Oct/2013:19:26:14 +0200] "POST /var/www/create_product.php HTTP/1.1" 404 448 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"`

And this if from the error.log file when trying to list all items: `[Wed Oct 09 17:01:51 2013] [error] [client 81.225.106.145] File does not exist: /var/www/var`
I get the same error when trying to create a new product.

Can you guys make anything out of this??

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any difference between WAMP/LAMP? Or can I use the same approach?**

Yes, there are differences - mostly related to networking and security. However, there's no reason the code in that tutorial wouldn't work Ubuntu.

Firstly, are you running both the web server and database on the same Ubuntu machine? If so, you can leave the "localhost" entry - you need to specify an IP address if the web server and database are on different machines. If everything's on the same server, that just complicates matters, and breaks when your IP address changes. You should certainly not use a public IP address (like 81.***.***.***), because then your traffic from the web server may well get routed out on the internet to reach your database.

Secondly, if PHPMyAdmin is running on the same server as your web app, there's no problem connecting from your web server to the database in principle.

Thirdly, have you tried accessing the URLs in a browser to see if they are working? If that doesn't work, the app can't won't be able to access them either. The tutorial mentions `http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php` - presumably you've changed that to `http://IPAddressOfUbuntuServer/android_connect/get_all_products.php`. First see if you can access that URL (to get it to go, you should put your files in /var/www/android_connect) via a browser, and work out what's going on. Once that works, try accessing that in the browser on the Android device; if that works, the app should too.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. 1. Yes you are correct. Changed it back to "localhost". 2. Yes they are on the same server. 3.  Yes this works. When running the app and trying to create new product I get this error from LogCat: `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.long.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` What does this mean?

Comment: That sounds like the server is sending back a response to the handset which the handset doesn't like. Try logging that response into LogCat to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, well the above text is the error message I get from LogCat, but I don't know what it means.

Comment: Ah - I've just looked at the code in the tutorial, and it looks like this is a fairly common problem with the JSON parser. Use one of the tools in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349618/what-tools-can-i-use-to-test-a-rest-api to re-create the POST request and see what the response is.

Comment: Ok, will take a look at that tonight!

Comment: I had to try this, even though I'm at work right now. :) I've been experimenting with the APIGEE.COM. I tried to re-create a POST request for create_product.php. As I see it, the input should be "NAME" and a value plus "PH_NUMBER" and a value. Whatever combinations I try I always get `{
  "success": 0,
  "message": "Required field(s) is missing"
}` So there's something wrong with the input to start with. get_all_products.php works just fine, but that doesn't need any input.

Comment: The return JSON looks valid to me. It's possible that your app is getting back a server-generated page like a 404 or 500 error. Check the log files on your server - most likely in /var/log/apache2 or similar location. Look for the error.log file, and see if there are any entries.

Comment: I'm using PHPMyAdmin to manage the SQL server, and when I insert a new row I can get the code at the same time. The code from phpmyadmin says for example `INSERT INTO `test`.`test1` (`PID`, `NAME`, `PH_NUMBER`) VALUES (NULL, 'Juni', '025022088');` while the corresponding line from the tutorial says `INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')"` There's some differences between these two, can that be a part of the problem or will it still work? EDIT: The "code" marks in the line from phpmyadmin messed the comment up a bit, but I hope you understand.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - the PHPMyAdmin code refers to a different table (test1 versus products), with different columns.

Comment: Yes I have changed the tables and columns, I just copy-pasted the tutorial line in the comment above. But in my php file it says `INSERT INTO test1(NAME, PH_NUMBER) VALUES('$NAME', '$PH_NUMBER')`, but in phpmyadmin it's like in my comment above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38909/discussion-between-neville-k-and-andysando)